# What is the correct 'Find Bug' update site to be used as Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I want to use 'Find Bug' as the static code review tool for java programs. I am trying to use the Find Bug plugin in Eclipse. 
I am referring to the details to install eclipse plug-in mentioned in FindBug official website [FindBugs update site](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/). But when I try with any of the sites mentioned for update I get the below network error :

```
Network connection problems encountered during search.
  Unable to access "http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse".
    Error parsing site stream. [Premature end of file.]
    Premature end of file.
    Error parsing site stream. [Premature end of file.]
    Premature end of file.
```

Does any one have idea on what is the correct url to be used ? or if I am missing anything else ? Or I have to check anyother settings in eclipse.
Eclipse Version : Version: 3.3.1.1

Comment: That site is working for me. It shows v2.0.2 available.

Comment: Could you give me a hint, why it could not be working for me ?

Comment: Post the full output you get from your browser or `wget`.

Comment: If you really use Eclipse 3.3, you should first consider using a current version, before solving other issues. 3.3 is more than 5 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look broken.  Abandoned really.  I had to install the plugin manually.

It's possible to download various version from [the FindBugs project's SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/findbugs/files/findbugs%20eclipse%20plugin/)

Comment: Howz that done, if you could give some hint. or it's like an installer and just unzip and install ?

Comment: Got it, it's just downloading the jar and dropping in eclipse's plugin directory, right ?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it worked fine.  Have to restart the IDE, of course.

Comment: Sorry for the silliy question, but how do you check the plug-in is available in the eclipse ide or not, I have restarted the IDE but I cant see any icon for FireBug.

Comment: Right click on a project and FindBugs will be near the bottom of the context menu.  Also there are two findbugs views added to the view list (Window->Views->Other).

Answer (score 2):

This update site is still usable.  My company includes it in their Certified Popular Pack for SDC which we build quarterly.

I have seen problems with update sites when a corporate firewall blocks access and doesn't give a good response back to you.

If you access the [site.xml](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/site.xml) in a browser and don't get a valid XML file back, your firewall is likely to blame.

Comment: I got the response : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <site>
  <description url="http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse">This is the Eclipse update site for FindBugs features.</description> 
- <feature url="features/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse_2.0.2.20121210.jar" id="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse" version="2.0.2.20121210">
  <category name="FindBugs" /> 
  </feature>
- <category-def name="FindBugs" label="FindBugs">
  <description>This is the Eclipse category for FindBugs features.</description> 
  </category-def>
  </site>

Comment: This looks like the expected content.  Do you know if your browser is proxied?  Proxies also can cause problems, particularly inside of Eclipse.